# Is there a way to bypass/circumvent the single class inheritance limit in C#.NET?

Tags: .net, oop, inheritance

I was recently asked in a interview if I knew of a way to bypass/circumvent the .NET limitation that classes can inherit only from a single class and not from multiple classes. Obviously I did not know the answer, otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question in here.  Short of implementing multiple interfaces (which seemed like a wrong answer) or chaining classes to where one inherits from another that inherits from another, is there another way to accomplish this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Short of implementing multiple interfaces (which seemed like a wrong answer) or chaining classes to where one inherits from another that inherits from another, is there another way to accomplish this that I'm not aware of?

No, and I suspect implementing multiple interfaces is the correct answer.

This is fairly standard. Say you have classes `Foo` and `Bar` and you want class `FooBar` to "inherit" from both `Foo` and `Bar`. Then you create interfaces `IFoo` and `IBar` and have `Foo : IFoo` and `Bar : IBar`. Then you'd define `FooBar : IFoo, IBar` and standard implementation would be

```
class FooBar : IFoo, IBar {
    private readonly IFoo foo = new Foo();
    private readonly IBar bar = new Bar();
    // or pass these in as dependencies

    public void Moo() {
        foo.Moo();
    }

    public void Mar() {
         bar.Mar();
    }
}
```

Yes, it *can* be a lot of writing, but it's not *that* hard (there are tools within VS or R# to help speed things up a *little* bit).

Comment: I believe object composition is the right way to go. In practice I've found `Foo` and `Bar` to be of higher quality when built separately from `FooBar`.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but I don't understand what the point is here? You still have to write the implementation of Moo and Mar methods in your FooBar class but granted the actual implementation is in the Foo and Bar classed while you only have a call to those methods. Is that the point of this structure?

Comment: The point is this is the *standard* way of mimicking multiple inheritance in C#. The implementation of `Moo` and `Mar` merely forwards the calls to the appropriate receiver, which is exactly what would happen in multiple inheritance. You can even *override* the behavior if you need to.

Comment: How would you override the behavior? Can you please demonstrate that?

Comment: @Marko: Instead of forwarding the call to `FooBar.Moo` to `Foo.Moo`, just implement new behavior. That is *don't* invoke, `foo.Moo`, instead do something else.

Comment: @Marko - You can easily apply your previous knowledge here. `Moo` is a method that can be changed so you call different code.